# C# LINQ .net core syntax issue with Inner Join and Where

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am writing a c# linq for inner join and where clause with .net core 3 and entityframework core. I looked at a few post here but the syntax are diffent and my visual studio 2019 intellisense is now showing me the correct table property.

Here is my code with issue completing the query

```
this.myDbContent.Table1
  .Join(this.myDbContent.Table2,
    table1 => table1.id,  // intellisense picked up this id for Table1
    table2 => table2.id,  // intellisense did now the table 2 properties, a drop shows [equals, getHashCode, getType, toString]
    (table1, table2) => new myViewModel
    {
      id = table1.id,
      name = table1.name
    }
  )
  .Where(table2 => table2.isCompleted === true) // intellisense is not showing the table 2 properties
```

I followed a linq post but I noticed that most post found are the older .net version,  I am using the lastest .net core and entityFrameworkCore. I am not sure why the intellisense is not showing for the table2 property to select. I following the demo post syntax as it is but not sure why is not working in my visual studio. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter of your `Join` call is the [`resultSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.join?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Queryable_Join__4_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___2___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___1___2___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___3___):

> **resultSelector** Expression<Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>>
>
> A function to create a result element from two matching elements.

So `table2` is of type `myViewModel`. You can do something like this:

```
this.myDbContent.Table1
  .Join(this.myDbContent.Table2,
    table1 => table1.id,  
    table2 => table2.id,  
    (table1, table2) => new {table1, table2}
  )
  .Where(jr => jr.table2.isCompleted == true)
```

Or apply filter in the join:

```
this.myDbContent.Table1
  .Join(this.myDbContent.Table2.Where(table2 => table2.isCompleted == true),
    table1 => table1.id,  
    table2 => table2.id,
    (table1, table2) => new myViewModel
    {
      id = table1.id,
      name = table1.name
    }
  )
```